# Is there a closed-form expression for the product $\prod_{i=0}^n (1+x_i)$ for $x_i$ non-commutative?

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a closed-form expression for the product

$$
P = \prod_{i=0}^n(1+x_i)
$$
for $x_i$ in a non-commutative ring.

Comment: Using the $\Pi$ notation for a product is a bit ambiguous if you aren't assuming that multiplication is commutative.  However, if you mean what I think you mean, the answer will be exactly the same as in a commutative ring, except care has to be taken to ensure that in every monomial in the result, the variables are in sorted order.  This follows from judicious application of the distributive law (and induction).

Comment: what is a closed-form of the product for commutative $x_i$?

Comment: @Leox Vieta's formulas.

Comment: @whacka Oh yeah, I forgot about that. I'll write it up for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @whacka suggested, the expression has to do with Vieta's formulas, but more specifically the elementary symmetric polynomials. By carrying out the products explicitly, one will recognize the form of the symmetric polynomials. Now, since we are in a non-commutative ring, we must make sure to get the order right, i.e. that the leftmost products appear first. We can thus write the product as

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i) = 1+e_1(x_1,\cdots,x_n)+\cdots+e_n(x_1,\cdots,x_n)
$$
where $e_i$ are the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) of the $n$ variables, written in the proper order.